# Get rid of nulls in function call

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have this function which should call a stored procedure in my database.

The stored procedure requires a lot of arguments, but only really needs three of them to run.

How can I make it so I only need to run the function with those three?
Below is working code, and an idea of what I thought would be a solution, but isn't.

```
public void UpdateOrderLine(int originalRecordId,int originalOrdered,  int ordered)
{
    //Working Code

    Db.Public_OrderLine_Update(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ordered, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, originalOrdered, null, null, null, null, null, null, originalRecordId, null,
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    //Idea

        Db.Public_OrderLine_Update(ordered: ordered, original_RecordId: originalRecordId, original_Ordered: originalOrdered);


}
```

When I try to run my idea, it says:

> Method Public_OrderLine_Update has 90 parameters but is invoked with 3 arguments

[image: Example of the Stored Procedure being executed]

Also, what is the best practice to do in this situation?

----- EDIT ------

Okay so the answer given below, would work but my SP requires 90 arguments, is there any way to generate these or do I just need to do the grunt work myself?

Comment: Just do what your idea says. Make a function with 3 arguments that updates only the appropriate things.

Comment: the problem is i already tried it and it gives an error where it says: "the method Public_OrderLine_Update has 90 parameters but is invoked with 3 arguments.

Comment: You should add that info to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper method that "breaks out" the parameters one-by-one, so that you could pass values explicitly, and keep passing `null`s implicitly:

```
static void PublicOrderLineUpdate(
    this MyDbContext DB
,   int? arg1 = null
,   double? arg2 = null
,   string arg3 = null
,   int? arg4 = null
,   /* and so on */
,   int? arg90 = null) {
    DB.Public_Order_LineUpdate(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., arg90);
}
```

Of course you would use long meaningful names for `arg1`, `arg2`, etc.

Now you can call your extension with C# syntax for passing named arguments:

```
Db.Public_OrderLine_Update(arg3: ordered, arg42: originalRecordId, arg67: originalOrdered);
```

Comment: My SP requires 90 arguments, is there any way to generate these or do i just need to do the grunt work myself?

Comment: You could probably create a code generator for it, but if it's just one and you ain't planning to make more again, you'll probably be faster monkey-typing it once

Comment: @BjørnHenneberg You will have to do that manually, but it should take very little typing, because you should be able to use the code already generated for your `Public_Order_LineUpdate` as the starting point (I am assuming that you use SP mapping from LINQ2SQL or EF).

Comment: You can also use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8397/C-Code-Generator-for-Stored-Procedures) as a starting point to make a C# generator (assuming SQL Server). You'd just have to change the outputted code to make function arguments (instead `SqlParameter`-lines)